# Extracting xml content with xpath expression

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following request:

```
<request>
   <sender>A</sender>
   <id>01</id>
   <parameters>
       <parameter value="1" />
       <parameter value="2" />
   </parameters>
</request>
```

I want to send the response:

```
<response>
   <id>01</id>
   <parameters>
       <parameter value="1" />
       <parameter value="2" />
   </parameters>
   <result>3</result>
</response>
```

So most of the response is the same : the id, the parameters. Is there a way to get a subset of xml full text with an xpath expression?
I would like to get :

```
   <id>01</id>
   <parameters>
       <parameter value="1" />
       <parameter value="2" />
   </parameters>
```

Optional question: is it possible to get only one string ?
Basically I want the result of my XPath evaluation to be :

```
   "<id>01</id>
   <parameters>
       <parameter value="1" />
       <parameter value="2" />
   </parameters>"
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, XPath is the wrong tool here.  (XPath 2.0 might be able to cobble together some transformation-like output, but you'll not be happy going that route.)  XPath is primarily for selection, but your task requires transformation.  Use XSLT for this instead.

Answer (score 1):

XPath can't create new nodes, or modify existing nodes: it can only select nodes that are already present in your input. You need XQuery or XSLT. It's simple enough (XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="request">
  <response>
    <xsl:copy-of select="id, parameters"/>
    <result>3</result>
  </response>
</xsl:template>
```